# Any way to use the range slider in ArcGIS Pro with a floating point raster?

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-layer, raster-conversion, floating-point

So I've created these classified floating point rasters showing specific heights. However, I need to enable range properties for them so that they can function with the range slider in ArcGIS Pro.

I am aware that this feature is only available for feature layers. I have tried converting the values to integers then using raster to polygon, however, that changed the values of many of them so the appearance was different (for example 3.9999 was now 3).

Is there a way then that I could directly transfer the rasters that I have into a different type of feature layer that could be range enabled? Maybe TIN or something else?

Their current appearance values must remain the way they are so I'm kind of in a bind.

Comment: "*I am aware that this feature is only available for feature layers*", this is incorrect. You can use a feature class, mosaic dataset, 
NetCDF layer, 
Image Service or a 
Feature Service. I suggest you try creating a mosaic dataset from your raster.

Comment: Or a NetCDF http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/netcdf/exporting-to-netcdf-data-from-a-raster.htm

Comment: @Luke I converted it to a NetCDF then to a NetCDF raster layer but it's telling me that there are no range values found. Is there some step that I'm missing? It has float point values assigned to each grid cell. I feel like I'm so close...